# Garden weed identification

Tags: species-identification, botany

I'd like to identify this weed found in a garden in northern England at this time of year (March).

It reproduces using underground roots rather than flowers - so if you dig it up and leave any behind it grows again.

EDIT: here's a photo with the bulb cleaned a bit.

[image]

[image]

Comment: if the leaves are cylindrical, with pointed tips, maybe Juncus spp. If you want info on how to grow (or get rid of) then ask to have the question moved to Gardening (or move yourself).

Comment: This certainly looks like a graminoid, but my guess would be a species of Poa. Very common for lawn grass, and when it doesn't get mowed they can get tall like this.

Comment: Is it possible to clean the roots in water to see the "bulb"?